# Any Unix with Windows XP like fonts?

Tags: linux, windows-xp, unix, fonts, bsd

I'd like to try a Linux- or BSD-based OS on my desktop. But all distros I've seen so far have fonts that feel unnatural after Windows XP. Could you recommend a distributive or a way to make them like XP with no ClearType?

A random screenshot found on the Net:

[image: XP fonts]

If you can recommend something, please attach a screenshot as well.

What I absolutely don't want to do is copying Tahoma from MS Windows.

Answer (score 2):

Most linux include pixel size similar fonts to those standard windows fonts, fonts like liberation.

If those aren't enough, most debian based distros have a package named *ttf-mscorefonts-installer* that will download and install the MS fonts.

You can also grab the fonts from a windows installed machine and copy then to your $HOME/.fonts . Then run fc-cache to update your X font cache